# Correlativo en rangos descontinuos excel

Tags: excel

tengo una duda.
saben como puedo asignar numeros o correlativo en rangos descontinuos?

[image: Excel]

la idea es que se repita el mismo hasta detectar el espacio, luego continue pero sumandole +1 
por ejemplo:
Empieza con un correlativo 1, luego al detectar el espacio y volver al encontrar datos aumente a 2 y asi incrementando hasta el final de la lista.
estoy usando la formula

```
=SI(B2="";"";CONTAR.SI(B2;"<>")+MIN(0;C1))
```

el 2 que muestro, es a modo de ejemplo ingresado manualmente.
la idea es que lo haga automaticamente por que son bastante filas intercaladas con espacios

Comment: Con una fórmula no se me ocurre la manera. Pero con una macro en VBA sí podrías hacerlo fácilmente. ¿No te sirve VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Creo entender tu pregunta y lo abordé de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fómula en D2 sería de la siguiente forma:

```
=+SI(                             -- primer condicional si

      B2="";                      -- si la celda B2 está vacía
         "";                      -- no asignar nada a la celda D2 

      SI(                         -- caso contrario
          Y(ESNUMERO(D1);D1<>""); -- si D1 es número y no está vació
                                  -- (esto último por los encabezados iniciales que
                                      puedas tener)

           D1;                    -- que la celda D2 sea igual a D1

           MAX($D$1:D1)+1         -- caso contrario tomar el valor máximo desde
                                  -- la celda D1 ($D$1) será fija siempre hasta la celda
                                  -- D n-1 es decir si estoy en D2 será D1

         )                        -- cerramos caso contrario
      )                           -- cerramos primer condicional si
```

Sin comentarios así quedaria:

```
=+SI(B2="";"";SI(Y(ESNUMERO(D1);D1<>"");D1;MAX($D$1:D1)+1))
```

Por favor tener en cuenta que lo hice en excel 2010 para mac, si hay diferencia entre las fórmulas por el sistema operativo y/o versión del excel que empleas, déjalo en los comentarios por favor, ya que en la macOS Sierra, no se cuenta con todas las prestaciones ofimáticas brindadas por MS y esto incluye VBA-Macros.